# no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive, but not listening on ssl

Tags: nginx

I try to redirect from http to https a custom port by adding:

```
server {
    listen 3000;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host:3000$request_uri;
}
```

Then I get error: `nginx: [emerg] no "ssl_certificate" is defined for the "listen ... ssl" directive in...`

I don't listen on `ssl` port, why do I get this error?

Note without the above code, configuration works correctly, just I cannot access `http://host:3000` but only `https://host:3000`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this [article](https://ma.ttias.be/force-redirect-http-https-custom-port-nginx/) explaining the workaround.

I need to remove the `server` redirect custom block, and add the following line inside my original ssl `server` block:

```
server {
    listen 3000 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:3000 ssl http2;
    error_page 497 https://$host:3000$request_uri;
```

`error_page 497 ...` is a nginx workaround for this issue.